# Exact age calculation in Cognito Forms (not rounded to the nearest neighbour)

Tags: cognito-forms

I used the following formula provided with modification:

```
Form.CampDate.Year - BirthDate.Year + (DateTime.Today.Month < BirthDate.Month or (DateTime.Today.Month = BirthDate.Month and DateTime.Today.Day < BirthDate.Day) ? -1 : 0)
```

I need the return result to show year and month—how do I go about it?

Example: my event date is 06 June 2016 and the birth date is 10 July 2012, so the result should be 3 years 11 month or round to age 3.5 instead of capture as age 4 year. What’s the correct Cognito Forms formula for this result?

Answer (score 1):

**Calculating Age in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com)**

You can use the following calculations to determine the age of someone based on a birth date in when writing calculations in Cognito Forms.  This is the official accurate way to calculate ages without rounding or mistakes due to leap years.

**Age in Years**

```
= DateTime.Today.Year - BirthDate.Year + (
if DateTime.Today.Month < BirthDate.Month or 
(DateTime.Today.Month = BirthDate.Month and 
DateTime.Today.Day < BirthDate.Day) then -1 else 0)
```

**Age in Months**

`=(DateTime.Today.Year - BirthDate.Year) * 12 + (DateTime.Today.Month - BirthDate.Month) + (if DateTime.Today.Day < BirthDate.Day then -1 else 0)`

**Age Description**

`="You are " + AgeInYears.ToString("d") + " years and " + (AgeInMonths - AgeInYears * 12).ToString("d") + " months old!"`

If you put the birthdate of the Statue of Liberty into these calculations, you will see that she is 129 years old today!

[image: example of age calculation using the birth date of the Statue of Liberty]

You can see these calculations in action on this shared form template:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/CognitoSupport/AgeCalculations